# Recyclerview dragging multiple viewtypes

Tags: android

Lets say I have 10 items in my recyclerview and item 4 is a different viewtype then the rest of the items. When dragging say item 0 across the recyclerview, there is a fade in and out effect on item 4 and that's because we don't swap elements with different viewtypes. Is there a way to avoid "refreshing" the adapter when we drag across different viewtypes?

```
@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    Collections.swap(mItems, fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    return true;
}
```

Here fromPosition is 3 and toPosition is 5 but at position 4 is an item with a different viewType.

Answer (score 0):

According to this tutorial with simple drag drop https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo I had to commented one line in `SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback`

```
@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder source, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    if (source.getItemViewType() != target.getItemViewType()) {
        //return false; //commented here
    }

    // Notify the adapter of the move
    mAdapter.onItemMove(source.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
    return true;
}
```